# what syscall/method could I use to get the default network gateway

Tags: networking, go, system-calls

Using [Go](https://golang.org/) what package, native function, syscall could be used to obtain the default gateway on a [*nix system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like)

I would like to avoid creating a wrapper arround [netstat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat), route, ip,  etc commands, or read, parse an existing file, the idea is to obtain the values the most [os/platform agnostic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-platform) way posible.

For example this is the output of the [route](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/route.8.html) command:

```
$ route -n get default
   route to: default
destination: default
       mask: default
    gateway: 192.168.1.1
  interface: en1
      flags: <UP,GATEWAY,DONE,STATIC,PRCLONING>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1500         0
```

I would like to do something simliar in order to just print/obtain the gateeway address/interface.

Comment: does `net.Interfaces()` contain the gateway? https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Interfaces

Comment: @dm03514 I do not believe it does.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need this?

Comment: @captncraig to know / print default gateways routes when using a VPN

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Play with the RoutedInterface() code at https://github.com/golang/net/blob/master/internal/nettest/interface.go

Sample code snip:

```
rifs := nettest.RoutedInterface("ip", net.FlagUp | net.FlagBroadcast)
if rifs != nil {
    fmt.Println("Routed interface is ",rifs.HardwareAddr.String())
    fmt.Println("Flags are", rifs.Flags.String())
}
```

Note:  You will need to copy the golang code into a local library, since /internal calls are not allowed directly.

Comment: Not sure why this got accepted, as the question asks about the gateway IP. If you look at the interface.go link, the code does nothing with gateways; it merely checks the addresses on the local interfaces and returns one it is happy with.

Comment: I was not able to retrieve the gateway IP of an interface using the nettest package. Can you be more specific ?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused here, the code above is actually correct, it does return the interface that has routable config. here is the link to sample code that actually works: https://play.golang.org/p/iIOQ136z3_B

Comment: @Ali for one, the question is not to find the local interface address, but to find the default gateway address, which is almost always a remote address; for another, simply finding _a_ "routable" interface does not guarantee that you have found _the_ interface which has the _default_ route

Answer (score 4):

For Linux, you can use the procfs as suggested by captncraig. Here is a snippet that extracts the gateway address and convert it to quad dotted ipV4.

```
/* /proc/net/route file:
Iface   Destination Gateway     Flags   RefCnt  Use Metric  Mask
eno1    00000000    C900A8C0    0003    0   0   100 00000000    0   00                                                                             
eno1    0000A8C0    00000000    0001    0   0   100 00FFFFFF    0   00 
*/

const (
    file  = "/proc/net/route"
    line  = 1    // line containing the gateway addr. (first line: 0)
    sep   = "\t" // field separator
    field = 2    // field containing hex gateway address (first field: 0)
)

func main() {

    file, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {

        // jump to line containing the agteway address
        for i := 0; i < line; i++ {
            scanner.Scan()
        }

        // get field containing gateway address
        tokens := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), sep)
        gatewayHex := "0x" + tokens[field]

        // cast hex address to uint32
        d, _ := strconv.ParseInt(gatewayHex, 0, 64)
        d32 := uint32(d)

        // make net.IP address from uint32
        ipd32 := make(net.IP, 4)
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(ipd32, d32)
        fmt.Printf("%T --> %[1]v\n", ipd32)

        // format net.IP to dotted ipV4 string
        ip := net.IP(ipd32).String()
        fmt.Printf("%T --> %[1]v\n", ip)

        // exit scanner
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the kind of things I would like to avoid, I would like to know some syscalls in order to make this more os agnostic

Comment: @nbari: syscalls won't make it any more OS agnostic, syscalls are even more system dependent. Each OS has its own tools for this which you need to use. You can probably find some subset of the `netstat` command which will print routing tables on most OSes, otherwise just call out to the appropriate command for each OS.

Comment: @JimB my goal of using the syscalls despite the fact I would have to maintain them and also cross-compile is to avoid depending on external commands, in that way I could produce an binary that could behave the same on almost all systems.

Comment: If you are going to customize the syscalls per-platform, you are going to have a file per platform with build tags anyways. If that uses a syscall or execs something, they are equally un-portable. Just exec the tool that is availible on your os.

Comment: imports would be nice ;)

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to read `/proc/net/route`. On one of my systems this contains:

```
Iface   Destination Gateway     Flags   RefCnt  Use Metric  Mask        MTU Window  IRTT                                                       
team0   00000000    010017BA    0003    0   0   0   00000000    0   0   0                                                                              
team0   0000070A    00000000    0001    0   0   0   00FEFFFF    0   0   0
```

You could read that in, capture the gateway with some text processing, and convert the hex string to a net.IP. Kinda a runaround, but I could not find any package that can access this for you in the std lib or elsewhere.

Comment: This seems to be on linux but what about unixes (freebsd, mac os, etc) I would like something os agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

There's [github.com/jackpal/gateway](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackpal/gateway). It supports multiple platforms and has a very straightforward interface:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/jackpal/gateway"
)

func main() {
    gatewayIP, err := gateway.DiscoverGateway()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Gateway IP:", gatewayIP)
}
```

It also has a `DiscoverInterface` function which can obtain the IP address of the interface through which the default gateway is reached.